# Show help inside visual studio 2010 when pressing F1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to show the msdn help inside VS2010 after pressing F1?

I can make it open the MS Help Viewer or in a web browser, but I want it to show right inside VS, using the embed web browser or (preferably) showing a local Help Viewer window inside VS2010.

Any way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

For VS2010, check out the [HelpViewerKeywordIndex](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4af86641-a302-4edf-9853-007bcc670b30/) in the Visual Studio Gallery.  If you've moved on to VS2012, try the [Integrated Help Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c7218602-e233-4441-a9bb-6f22638470a9).